# how to add a row dynamically in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am able to add a row dynamically in a GridView through the following code but I need to do the same to be captured and displayed in Application every time when I open the application with the records I have added previously in the GridView. 
Any Ideas??

Coding:

```
    ![enter image description here][1] protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }

    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
       dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
       dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    // ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        Application["CurrentTable"]=dt;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

       //if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        if (Application["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            //DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataTable dtCurrentTable1 = (DataTable)Application["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable1.NewRow();
                   drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    /*dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;*/
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
             //ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
                Application["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable1;
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable1;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        //if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        if (Application["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            //DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)Application["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    /*box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();*/
                    box1.Text = dt1.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt1.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt1.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your question you are talking about when the application is opened, what you will need to do is have a method to save the data in the grid view somewhere, i.e. Database, Text File etc.

This is because the Application variable is lost when the application is closed, so to re-open at the last point you will need to read the data you saved either in a Database or a Text file and re-create the DataTable object from that.

Comment: Is it not possible without storing it in a database or a text file? Can I able to do using Application variable which I have already used here.. or using any other similar concepts..

Comment: The application variable is lost after the application closes (i.e. Closing of browser window) so it no longer exists. If you want the data to persist after closing and reopening the browser, external storage (i.e. Text File / Database) is the only way to achieve this. If this is a web app (or site) which the Grid View suggests it is, I would suggest a database as the easiest option.

Comment: Can you provide me some examples for storing the values in database in a separate table so that I can able to retrieve the values which I have used at the last point .. Because I am struck and I don't know how to take this forward..

Comment: Are you having trouble creating the database or simply storing the data? And what database system are you using? SQL?

Comment: I am using Oracle database.. In my scenario I will be having 7 text boxes denoting 7 days of a week and a drop down having list of activities to schedule for that particular week in the grid view.. I will be capturing the number of hours spent in each text box pertaining to each activity and I will calculate total for each day..Hence I am capturing only the total values of each day.. If I want to display each and every text box value from the last point how I achieve this by storing in Oracle database

Comment: I think that the problem has now changed from the initial question you asked, could you ask a new question more related to the current problem. Someone might be able to help you in more detail with this issue.