# Gridview adding a row with ajax, but not deleting with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a Gridview that adds and deletes rows fine, but it only adds rows without a refresh. I need it to delete rows without a refresh. I have the whole thing in am UpdatePanel, but the delete command still refreshes the page. I am using a Master Page. Here is my markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TextAnalyzer.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="Upload4.aspx.cs" Inherits="TextAnalyzer.Upload4" EnableEventValidation="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<!-- Using Ajax panels to set sessionvars before upload is started    -->
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">

</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>



    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpnlStep1" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>


<div id="Tasks" style="float: left; width: 100%; border: 0px solid red;">



                <asp:GridView ID="gridTasks" runat="server" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyNames="TaskNumber" OnRowDataBound="gridTasks_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="gridTasks_DataBound"
                    OnRowCommand="gridTasks_RowCommand" GridLines="None" >

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskNumber" HeaderText="Task #" Visible="true" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Window Size">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParameter1" runat="server" >
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Centrality">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParameter2" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add/Remove">

                            <HeaderStyle />
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"
                                    Text="Add Summary Task" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server"
                                    Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0096D6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0096D6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>

            </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

and my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace TextAnalyzer
{
public partial class Upload5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            AddNewRowToGrid();
        }
    }


    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow drNewRow = null;

        if (Session["CurrentTable"] == null)
        {
            dtCurrentTable = InitDataTableCols(dtCurrentTable);
        }
        else
        {
            dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
        }

        drNewRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            drNewRow["TaskNumber"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            drNewRow["TaskNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32((dtCurrentTable.Rows[dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1] as DataRow)[0].ToString()) + 1;
        }

        drNewRow["Parameter1"] = string.Empty;
        drNewRow["Parameter2"] = string.Empty;

        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        BindGridFromNewDataAndSendToSession(dtCurrentTable);

        //Session["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
        //gridTasks.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        //gridTasks.DataBind(); 
    }

    private void BindGridFromNewDataAndSendToSession(DataTable myDataTable)
    {
        Session["CurrentTable"] = myDataTable;
        gridTasks.DataSource = myDataTable;
        gridTasks.DataBind(); 
    }

    DataTable InitDataTableCols(DataTable myTable)
    {
        myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TaskNumber", typeof(string)));
        myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Parameter1", typeof(string)));
        myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Parameter2", typeof(string)));

        return myTable;
    }


    //http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/398783/Exporting-a-grid-view-to-datatable
    DataTable GetDataTableFromCurrentGridValues(GridView myGrid)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = InitDataTableCols(dt);

        // add the columns to the datatable            
        //if (myGrid.HeaderRow != null)
        //{

        //    for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        //    {
        //        dt.Columns.Add(myGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
        //    }
        //}

        //  add each of the data rows to the table
        foreach (GridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["TaskNumber"] = row.Cells[0].Text;
            dr["Parameter1"] = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlParameter1") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            dr["Parameter2"] = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlParameter2") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982343/how-to-add-a-row-dynamically-in-gridview

    private void PutCurrentGridIntoSession()
    {
        Session["CurrentTable"] = GetDataTableFromCurrentGridValues(gridTasks);
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PutCurrentGridIntoSession();
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }

    private void FillSummWinSizeDDL(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> lstSummWinSize = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        lstSummWinSize.Add("3", "3");
        lstSummWinSize.Add("4", "4");
        lstSummWinSize.Add("5", "5");
        lstSummWinSize.Add("6", "6");

        ddl.DataSource = lstSummWinSize;
        ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
        //ddl.SelectedValue = "4";
        ddl.DataBind();

    }

    private void FillSummCentralityDDL(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> lstCentrality = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        lstCentrality.Add("degree", "Degree");
        lstCentrality.Add("betweenness", "Betweenness");
        lstCentrality.Add("closeness", "Closeness");
        lstCentrality.Add("eigenvector", "Eigenvector");
        lstCentrality.Add("weighted_degree", "Weighted Degree");

        ddl.DataSource = lstCentrality;
        ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
        //ddl.SelectedValue = "degree";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }


    protected void gridTasks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drview = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            DropDownList ddlParam1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlParameter1");
            DropDownList ddlParam2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlParameter2");


            FillSummWinSizeDDL(ddlParam1);
            FillSummCentralityDDL(ddlParam2);            


            if (Session["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable1 = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];

                if (dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex] != null)
                {
                    if ((dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][1] != null) && (dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][1].ToString() != ""))
                    {                            
                        ddlParam1.Items.FindByValue(dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][1].ToString()).Selected = true;                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlParam1.SelectedValue = "4";
                    }

                    if ((dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][2] != null) && (dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][2].ToString() != ""))
                    {                           
                        ddlParam2.Items.FindByValue(dtCurrentTable1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][2].ToString()).Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlParam2.SelectedValue = "degree";
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Text == "Window Size")
                {
                    cell.Text = @"<span class='toolTip' title='This is a summary task window size tool tip.'>" + cell.Text + @"</span>";
                }
                if (cell.Text == "Centrality")
                {
                    cell.Text = @"<span class='toolTip' title='This is a summary task centrality tool tip.'>" + cell.Text + @"</span>";
                }

            }
        }
    }

    protected void gridTasks_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridTasks.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            (gridTasks.Rows[0].FindControl("btnDelete") as Button).Enabled = false;

        }
    }

    protected void gridTasks_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {

        }
    }



    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromCurrentGridValues(gridTasks);

        //Get the button that raised the event
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        //Get the row that contains this button
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(gvr.RowIndex);

        BindGridFromNewDataAndSendToSession(dt);
    }
}
}
```

I don't know if I'm missing something little but I haven't been able to figure it out for a while now. I thought that anything in an UpdatePanel becomes ajaxified, no?

I've updated the code and it's still the same. :/

---

Edited for working solution
I had to get rid of the delete command and OnDeleting and just went with another button on the suggestion of user Programmin Tool - RIP

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Does the linkbutton have an onclick to perform a postback?

Comment: The html and table look fine and work, but the row delete isn't ajaxified, so it breaks the rest of my page. I got rid of everything but the UpdatePanel and the grid and it's breaking the same way here.

Comment: Have you tried to set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `UpdateMode="Conditional"` but that didn't work. Its adds rows fine, but still refreshes for delete.